# How can I run seeral MATLAB programs (M-files) on different nodes of a cluster computer?

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing

I have access to a cluster with 8 nodes, each node has 8 cores. I should run several MATLAB programs (as M-files) on the cluster. How I can assign the jobs to the nodes other than the head node?

Comment: You have the parallel computing toolbox?

Comment: It highly depends on your cluster/grid infrastructure. Add more details if you want to get some answers back :)

Comment: Even better, ask the administrator of the cluster.